# unclear on statistical probability

Tags: probability

i believe that (1/4)^30 tells me the probability of hitting a 1 in 4 chance 30 consecutive  times...if this is correct how do i calculate the odds of missing a 1 in 4 chance 30 consecutive times? I understand that each time it is 1 in 4 or that there is a 75 % chance of failure..but the chance of missing a 1 in 4 chance 30 consecutive times cannot still be 75%..this is where i am stuck..any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The same idea, $(3/4)^{30}$. Much higher, but still quite  low!

Comment: thank you..i was curious if that that was correct...seemed a logical extension to me..similar to taking an inverse...but i wasn't sure so many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. If $p$ is the probability an event happens, then $1-p$, in our case $3/4$, is the probability it does not happen.  Now if the experiment is repeated **independently** $30$ times in a row, then by the multiplication principle the probability we get failure every time is $(1-p)^{30}$.

Answer (score 1):

The Keyword is "Binomial Distribution".

We have a series of $n$ Bernoulli events with success rate $p$.   Here $n=30$ and $p=1/4$.   The count of successes, $X$, has a Binomial Distribution. $~X\sim\mathcal {Bin}(n,p)$

Meaning the probability of $k$ successes, for $k\in\{0, 1,\ldots, n\}$, is $$\mathsf P(X=k)~=~\dbinom{n}{k}~p^n~(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Here the relevant probabilities are $k=30$ and $k=0$

The probability of all successes: $\mathsf P(X=30) ~=~ \binom{30}{30}(\frac 1 4)^{30} (\tfrac 3 4)^{0} ~=~ (\tfrac 1 4)^{30}$

The probability of no successes: $\mathsf P(X=0) ~=~ \binom{30}{0}(\frac 1 4)^{0} (\tfrac 3 4)^{30} ~=~ (\tfrac 3 4)^{30}$

---

**Too Long, Didn't Read:** It is exactly as you suspected.

The probability of 30 successes is the success rate raised to the power of thirty.

The probability of 30 failures is the failure rate raised to the power of thirty.

Now ... Can you find the probability of exactly 15 successes and 15 failures (in any order)?